# How to return max or NULL if no values in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
page
p_key   name
1       home
2       projects
3       contacts

article
p_key   page_id     seq (+ other article content fields)
1         1           1
2         1           2
3         1           3
4         2           1
5         2           2
```

article.seq specifies the order in which articles are to appear on a page.

I need a query that will return a single record containing page.p_key and the current maximum article.seq for articles on that page, or NULL if there are no articles for that page.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT p.p_key, a.seq FROM page p 
LEFT JOIN article a ON p.p_key = a.page_Id 
WHERE a.seq = 
    (SELECT MAX(seq) FROM article a2 
     WHERE a2.page_id = 1);
```

This works correctly for this value of p.p_key, returning [1, 3]

However, if a page has no articles (e.g. if I change 'WHERE a2.page_id = 1' to 'WHERE a2.page_id = 3') the  query returns no records.  What I need is for it to return [3, NULL] (I'm looking for a LEFT JOIN).

I confess my SQL is a bit rusty, so how do I achieve this?

Comment: The problem is the where clause is making the join as if it were an inner join.  As a.seq max will eliminate nulls.  you resolve this by having the limit imposed on the table as part of the join so the limit is imposed before the join occurs, allowing the nulls in.

Comment: If I change the first WHERE to AND it returns multiple rows - I only want a single row (for the specified page).

Comment: DISTINCT will fix that

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of what you want, I don't understand the `a2.page_id = 1` in your query.  The following should return what you are asking for:

```
SELECT p.p_key,
       (SELECT MAX(a.seq)
        FROM article a
        WHERE p.p_key = a.page_Id
       ) as seq
FROM page p ;
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `article(page_Id, seq)`.

EDIT:

For a particular page, you would put a `WHERE` clause in the *outer* query:

```
SELECT p.p_key,
       (SELECT MAX(a.seq)
        FROM article a
        WHERE p.p_key = a.page_Id
       ) as seq
FROM page p
WHERE p.p_key = $page;
```

Comment: If I add a final WHERE to this it works:  WHERE p.p_key = 1 (the 1 obviously being a parameter).  If you could amend your answer I'll flag it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Question - is there something MySQL does(nt?) do that changes performance aspects as compared to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30398791/812837)?  Granted, this is a simple setup (and there are multiple ways to write this)...

Comment: With the `where` clause, the performance should be similar.  Without the `where` clause, the correlated subquery can take advantage of an index on `article` for the aggregation, so there is not a separate aggregation step.  So, in fact, there is something that MySQL doesn't do, and that is offer alternative aggregation algorithms that actually make use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The other general way to do this is a `GROUP BY` with the join, and most aggregate functions will return null results for null source data:

```
SELECT Page.p_key, MAX(Article.seq)
FROM Page
LEFT JOIN Article
       ON Article.page_id = Page.p_key
-- WHERE Page.p_key = 1
GROUP BY Page.p_key
```

Returns the expected results:

```
p_key    MAX(Article.seq)    
1        3 
2        2 
3        (null)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4868e/1/0)</kbd>